Wildberries API - reportDetailByPeriod
Доброго времени суток.
Возникла проблема с WB API, конкретно метод по получению данных по продажам:
https://openapi.wildberries.ru/statistics/api/ru/#tag/Statistika/paths/~1api~1v5~1supplier~1reportDetailByPeriod/get
Вопрос связан не с кодом, а с самим методом(мб кто то с ним уже работал).
Метод принимает в headers 4 параметра - Дата начала отчета, Лимит на кол-во строк(WB не отдаст за один запрос более 100000 строк), Дата окончания отчета и rrdid - это идентификатор строки отчета.
Даты выставлены за 3 месяца(WB в данном методе отдает только 3 месяца)
Первым запросом в метод rrdid - передается с значением "0".
После чего, что бы получить данные более 100000 строк, нужно из последней строки ответа json, получить этот rrdid и передать его снова метод, что бы получить новые строки отчета.
Вместе с тем, WB постоянно мне возвращается одни и те же первые строки отчета.
Пример параметров запроса:
Дата начала - 2024-04-01,
Дата окончания - 2024-07-01,
rrdid- 0
Лимит - 100000
При первом запросе я получаю свои корректные данные, извлекаю последнюю строку json, и ее rrdid, после вызываю метод снова и отдаю rrdid уже  ему. Но в итоге WB снова присылает совершенно идентичный, первый кусок отчета.


Метод принимает в headers 4 параметра

Ну совсем не так! Обязательный заголовок лишь один - Authorization. А четыре параметра передаются в строке запроса.
